# Cant access an object property in laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5, sentinel

I am getting results from a database in a controller and storing them as objects in an array

```
    $roleSentinel = Sentinel::findRoleByName($role);
    $permisssionsName = array_keys($roleSentinel['permissions']);
    $permissions = array();

    foreach ($permisssionsName as $permiso) {
        $permissions[] = DB::table('sec_permission')->where('name', '=',$permiso)->get();
    }

    return view('menu', ['role' => $role,'permisos' => $permisos]);
```

an object would be like

```
[{"permission_id":1,"name":"foo","object_id":1,"operation_id":1}]
```

So then in the view I am trying to get the values and printing them

```
<b>{{$role}}</b><br>
    @foreach ($permisos as $permiso)
         @foreach ($permiso->name as $name)
            {{$name}}
        @endforeach
    @endforeach
```

however I am getting `Undefined property: Illuminate\Support\Collection::$name`

Comment: just wondering why you wouldn't use relations and eager loading for this?

Comment: No real reason its just that its a database that I didnt create so I am going column by column for now

Comment: It looks like you already have relational ids in place in database. I think it would be a lot easier if you create relations in your model and do a eager loading

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each variable in the array is an array of objects. There's two ways you can go about it.

Add another foreach:

```
@foreach ($permisos as $permiso)

    @foreach ($permiso as $perm)
        @foreach ($perm->name as $name)
           {{$name}}
        @endforeach
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Or get one full collection with all of the names:

```
$permissionsName = array_keys($roleSentinel['permissions']);

$permissions = DB::table('sec_permission')->whereIn('name',$permissionsName)->get();
```